# Java Method to Read JSON Elements

Tags: java, json, getjson

JSON is easy to use but sometime writing multiple child elements gives pain to write getJSONObject("") again and again in Java. Is there any simple way to avoid repetitive calls and have code more clean?

Comment: Parse the JSON into Lists and Maps and then access that structure.  It's very simple.

Comment: @HotLicks I have scenario where my JSON will not always have same element, with Lists and Maps index will be dependency.For Example we have below scenario where in one scenario we will have value in NewQuote and other we don't then List and Maps will allow <String> to be at 2nd after quote and for large XML its hard to manage. With my approach, regardless of location i am going by Tag names and if it exist it works else return "". Might be not clean approach but i am tester and thought of sharing my experience.          <Quote><NewQuote></NewQuote><String></String></Quote>

Comment: That makes no sense.  With any scheme, if there are omitted elements you must figure that out somehow.

Comment: Well those omitted elements are valid Scenarios, so in my case i am comparing My Request and Suppliers Response, now its not necessary for them to send me all Requested data. Anyways as i said my approach here is to read JSON Elements as it is by just passing element in tree format. Might be wrong, will do more research on List and Maps and see how much effort that need compare to below.

Answer (score -1):

After trying multiple round i came up with below approach, You just pass JSON Object and all elements with "/" to below Java method and it will read JSON value. Note- This code is more for string value and you can customize it more based on your needs.

```
public static String getJSONTagValue(JSONObject partData, String xpath) {
    String output="";
    String[] getPrmString=xpath.split("/");
    try {
        if (partData.has(getPrmString[0])){
            for (int i=0;i<getPrmString.length;i++){
                if (partData.has(getPrmString[i]) && i!=getPrmString.length-1){

                        partData=partData.getJSONObject(getPrmString[i]);

                } else if (partData.has(getPrmString[i])) {
                    output=partData.get(getPrmString[i])+"";
                    if (output.contains("xsi:nil")){
                        output="";
                    } else if (output.contains(".0")){
                        output=output.replace(".0", "");
                    } 
                }               
            }           
        }
        if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(output)){
            System.out.println("Missing xpath in Response ",xpath);
        } 
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("Missing xpath in Response ",xpath)
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```